# Binding object array to AngularJs component

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have a component with ui-gid inside, and I want to pass data to grid. Data comes from $http call to Web Api. 
Data is not shown when it arrives from server - grid inside a component is empty.
The problem is that binding occurs "to early", before data arrives from server. What is a proper way to bind object array to a component?

This is my component part:

```
.component('gridComponent', {
        bindings: {
            gridData: '<',
            gridSelected: '<?', //selected objects to set
            gridColumns: '<?',
            gridOnchange: '&',
        },
        templateUrl: 'Angular/common/components/grid-component/grid.component.html',
        controller: GridComponentController
    });

ctrl.$onInit = function () {
        if (angular.isDefined(ctrl.gridColumns))
            ctrl.grid.columnDefs = ctrl.gridColumns;
        ctrl.grid.data = ctrl.gridData;

    };
```

Html:

```
<grid-component  grid-data="vm.shops" grid-columns="vm.shopsColumns" grid-selected="vm.selectedShops"
                          grid-onchange="vm.changeSelected(selected, isChecked)"></grid-component>
```

I also tried to make two-way binding, but no luck.
The only way it worked is when I put ng-if=vm.shops.length>0 to some div that wraps this component, but I think this is not good solution.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I edited a question with a problem. The grid is not showing data that comes from server, it shows only hardcoded data from page controller(not component controller)

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code or try to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?